# Disable authentication for given action in the same controller

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, hadoop, php-5.4

I have the following code snippet in my controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    ...
    $this->Auth->allow('email');
}

public function email() {
    ...
    $this->show();
    ...
}

public function show() {
    ...
}
```

My `show` action needs authentication but `email` not.

The `email` action stands for accepting the jobEndNotifier's notification when my hadoop job finishes, so I can't have authentication on that page as it will be visited by hadoop.
( https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobEndNotifier.html )

My `show` action basically generates and visualizes reports for the finished hadoop job, and when my job finishes I want to automatically generate them (cache them) in the system, so later when the user visits the page, it will be loaded from the cache and will be much faster. This is the reason I'm calling the `show` action from the `email` action.

Of course I can access the `email` action without logging in by default, but when I call the `show` action from `email` it will redirect me to the home page saying you have to be logged in.

So in brief: Can I set that if I call the `show` action from my `email` action, that it will not need authentication? As the page is not rendered, only calculation is done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get with the code in the question? From what you describe the code in `show` should be in a model - which is called by both controller actions. However it'll just work as described which probably means you're looking at an error and making a false assumption. `it will redirect me to the home page saying you have to be logged in.` <- what does that redirect? It's not the auth component.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing this out. I thought first that this is an 'automatic' redirection because of the Auth Component as authentication is needed for the `show` action, but not, it was me by checking other conditions which failed. Now it's working, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As per your logic,
    $this->Auth->allow('email'); 
to bypass authentication for email method,

Same way you can set to bypass show from within email function like

```
public function beforeFilter() {
$this->autoRender = false;
...
$this->Auth->allow('email');
}

public function email() {
...
$this->Auth->allow('show'); /* allow show here **/
$this->show();
...
}

 public function show() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that will affect anything?